# Set audit parameters with no startup

Tags: oracle, startup, audit

I want to activate an audit operation on a table or two in my oracle db,
and for that I need to set the audit parameters.

```
alter system set AUDIT_SYS_OPERATIONS=true scope=spfile;
alter system set AUDIT_TRAIL=db, extended scope=spfile;
```

But those parameters not realy changed becuase startup of DB is needed.

Is there a way to skip over the startup to apply those changes?

This is realy important DB in production Env, and startup is almost-impossible.

Thank you.

Comment: but i need to set the "audit_sys_operations" to true, right? Also,i want to see the sql_text, and for that i need the db, extended..

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to enable auditing on a selected objects then you can do it without bouncing your database instance. Audit trail is set to `DB` by default.

```
SQL> show parameter audit

NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- ------------------------------
audit_file_dest                      string      /u01/app/oracle/admin/orcl/adu
                                                 mp
audit_sys_operations                 boolean     FALSE
audit_syslog_level                   string
audit_trail                          string      DB
```

All you need to do is to enable required auditing on that object.

```
SQL> conn jay
Enter password: 
Connected.

SQL> audit select on my_table;

Audit succeeded.


SQL> conn system 
Enter password: 
Connected.
SQL> select * from jay.my_table;

no rows selected
```

Audit information can be accessed from `USER_AUDIT_OBJECT` view.

```
SQL> conn jay
Enter password: 
Connected.

SQL> select username, action_name from user_audit_object where obj_name='MY_TABLE';

USERNAME                       ACTION_NAME
------------------------------ ----------------------------
SYSTEM                         SESSION REC
```

However, if you need to enable auditing for sysdba/sysoper privileged users such as sys then you need to set `audit_sys_operations` parameter to `true` which in turn requires database shutdown.

Moreover, if you are using Oracle 12c then `AUDIT_SYS_OPERATIONS` is set to `true` by default.

```
Connected to:
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production

SQL> show parameter audit

NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- ------------------------------
audit_file_dest                      string  /u01/app/oracle/admin/orcl/adump
audit_sys_operations                 boolean     TRUE
audit_syslog_level                   string
audit_trail                          string      DB
```

Comment: Yes. ok. that what i want because i need to see the sql_text value. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, `SQL_TEXT` is not unavailable unless you set the audit trail to `DB,EXTENDED`.

Comment: Yes, i got it.. so I cant get it with no startup.

Answer (score 0):

you cant use it with no startup

> look this [(Auditing Administrative Users)](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/network.102/b14266/cfgaudit.htm#i1007942)

Comment: I dont get it.. how?